# Laravel routing with resource

Tags: php, laravel

Currently my routes file looks like this:

```
Route::get('/corporation/{paginate}','Corporation\CorporationController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['active']], function () {

    /* Corporation */
    Route::resource('corporation','Corporation\CorporationController');

}
```

So I would expect that when I go to `/corporation` I'would not use the resource route. But it does -_-

How can I make sure that it uses the first route?

Many thanks!

--EDIT--

```
Route::post('/user', 'User\UserController@store');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['active']], function () {

    /* User */
    Route::resource('user', 'User\UserController');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to use the resource route because `/corporation` does not meet the standards of `/corporation/{paginate}`.

Since im guessing you want `/corporation/{paginate}` to be optional and use resource routes for the rest of the urls, you should make paginate optional by adding a `?` sign.

```
Route::get('/corporation/{paginate?}', 'Corporation\CorporationController@index');
```

Aditionaly you would need to exclude the default GET `/corporation` from the resources.

```
Route::resource('corporation', 'Corporation\CorporationController', ['except' => [
    'index'
]]);
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. That's working, but now I've it with another route? Please see my edit.

Comment: what is wrong with these routes? Its not necessary declaring the first route, since that route is being created by the resources route

Comment: Yes but I've to acces it without the `active` middleware.

Comment: just add the exception to the resource route `['except' => ['store']]`

Comment: [Laravel 5.2 Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) suggest you read a little bit on this, very usefull